# I am trying to use php function transliterator_transliterate but get an error when I call it

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to use this function in php7 and in Laravel framework

transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [\u0080-\uffff] remove', $str);

Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Core\Blog\transliterator_transliterate()

http://php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php

It's supposed to be available on (PHP >= 5.4.0, PECL intl >= 2.0.0)

Do I need some extension for this function?

Comment: Did you try this \transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [\u0080-\uffff] remove', $str); ?

Comment: Call to undefined function transliterator_transliterate()

Comment: is php5-intl installed?

Comment: This might work. echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure package `php-intl` is installed:

```
sudo apt install php-intl
sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
```

otherwise when you try to run the `transliterator_transliterate()` you get error `Call to undefined function`.

[Source](https://www.jasom.net/php-prepare-sanitize-transliterate-convert-change-user-string-input-for-filename-or-url-address/)